# Shaping reward so that it maximizes multiple components together

Tags: reinforcement-learning, rewards, reward-functions, reward-shaping

I am fairly new to RL and I compete in AWS DeepRacer student league. The main task there is to create a reward function. All the hyperparameters and action space are fixed. So far, I know how to shape a single component like speed or steering. I always do like steer_reward^2 or speed^2. But when I try to combine the components together, I am not seeing good results. Is it best to mutliply or add components and are there any resource where I find various maximization functions?

Comment: Hey, check these answers: [one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28291/how-would-you-shape-a-reward-function-if-there-was-four-quantities-to-optimize/28298#28298), [two](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/how-should-i-define-the-reward-function-to-solve-the-wumpus-game-with-deep-q-lea/24164#24164). Did they answer your question?

Comment: @ArayKarjauv Nope. I am trying find out functions that have a good global minimum or maximum where the variables of the functions are the speed or steering or other params.